# Multiple FireDAC packages in RAD Sever

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am working with Delphi 10.3.3 and a Rad Server installed on a Windows Server 2012.
I deployed two single data module package (.bpl) without any database access and I can invoke the corresponding resource without any problems.
When I put a FireDAC connection on one of the two packages everything carry on working well.
I tried to put a FireDAC connection on both packages and the second stop responding and I get an unknown resource when I try to invoke it.

Is there something I should consider when I deploy two packages with a FireDAC database access components inside to get responds from them?

Thank you,
Davide

Comment: Could you please write a very small program which reproduce the issue you describe, then edit your question with the code you wrote. Important: make it very minimal and ready for us to copy to test your code. Also, be sure to mention which line of code triggers the error you mention.

Comment: Try putting a TFDManager in the first BPL to load. Or make a separate BPL with TFDManager, load it first, and then load the other two BPLs. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Multithreading_(FireDAC)